# Idioms and Formal Usage

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, idioms, vocabulary

Certain websites devoted to idioms claim that they--idioms-- are not used in formal conversations or writing; that is, they claim that these creatures are always used in only informal situations. As the site is a British website, is this a common belief among the British, or is this a mere hiccup in the website? For "according to" and "at first glance"
are far from "informal".

Comment: Are you referring to phrases.org.uk? best to link to the site in your question, and to the claims about what is informal.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that the term *idiom* has various definitions. I would be surprised if the websites you refer to make the claim that a.) *according to* and *at first glance* are idioms and b.) such idioms are not used in formal conversations or writing. This is simply not true.

A narrower definition of *idiom* is that an idiom is *a phrase whose meaning cannot be deduced from its constituent words*. Examples are:

> She's having kittens. = She feeling nervous.
>
> You get up my nose. = You irritate me.

It is true that informal language abounds with idioms in this sense of the word. It is also true that you would not expect to see some of these idioms in formal conversations or writing. It is not true, however, to claim that no idioms are found in such situations.

Here are just three examples from the *Telegraph*, a serious British newspaper:

> The latest *can of worms* to burst open is the notion that an
>   independent Scotland should have a properly funded pension scheme.
>
> Iran decides to give its Western adversaries *a taste of their own
>   medicine*.
>
> Disagreements within the Conservative Party about Europe dominate the
>   headlines this morning, but it's *a storm in a teacup* compared to
>   Labour's deep ideological divisions.